# Incorrect text outline in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, lettering

I'm trying to convert a letter "A" to a shape using the Type -> Create Outline function. However, the converted shape does not maintain the straight lines in the letter.

Here is the original letter (before outline)
[image]

and zoomed in to the bottom right corner.

[image]

After being outlined, it looks like this

[image]

If you look closely at the bottom right corner (red arrow). The base of the letter is not horizontal (see red line for reference).

Could anyone reproduce this / explain why this is going on? I'm using the Helvetica Neue (Bold) font.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a problem with »Align to Pixel Grid«

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator has some troubles with this, especially when you align to pixels or grids. It can help to do the same task **in larger scale (x10 e.g.)** and then scale down or create a symbol (which generally helps avoiding errors when scaling).

Answer (score 0):

Try Object -> Expand

Does that bring any changes?
Btw I can't guess if there is any difference in these algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is either. They both give the same results. I've realized illustrator doesn't like this particular font (Helvetica Neue). With the regular Helvetica it works fine. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ye, I had not just "Helvetica Neue", but "Helvetica Neue Cyrillic", so expanding in Ai worked fine with it